# How to use linq in jsondata in microsoft.clearscript.v8

Tags: c#, linq, v8, clearscript

I am use microsoft.clearscript.v8 in asp .net core mvc,
in the Linq Where condition is not work in my code,
this is my homecontroller.cs code

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    using (var engine = new V8ScriptEngine())
    {
        string json = @"
        [
            { ""id"": 1, ""name"": ""John"", ""age"": 25 },
            { ""id"": 2, ""name"": ""Jane"", ""age"": 30 }      
        ]";

        // Parse JSON as JArray
        var jsonArray = JArray.Parse(json);

        // Use ClearScript to filter the data
        engine.Script.PersonList = jsonArray.ToObject<List<dynamic>>();
        engine.AddHostType(typeof(Enumerable));
        engine.AddHostType("Pred", typeof(Func<dynamic, bool>));

        engine.Execute(@"var result = PersonList.Where(new Pred(p => p.age > 25)).ToList();");

        // Retrieve the result from the script engine
        List<dynamic> filteredList = engine.Script.result;

        // Print filtered results
        foreach (var person in filteredList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Id: {person.id}, Name: {person.name}, Age: {person.age}");
        }
    }
    return view();
}
```

I expecting the Output is the `id : 2, name : Jane, age : 30` with using Linq Where condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `p => p.age > 25`, `p.age` has type `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue`, making the comparison undefined (and, hence, not `true`).

The actual `JValue.Value` is an `Int64` (`long`) and it supports conversion by `Convert`. Therefore, you can fix it by converting the value to `int` (or `long`, if you want):

Add:

```cs
engine.AddHostType(typeof(Convert));
```

And change the script line into:

```cs
@"var result = PersonList.Where(new Pred(p => Convert.ToInt32(p.age) > 25)).ToList();"
```